# Shortcut move cursor to the next/previous param in method android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a method with many parameter, and I want to move the cursor (next/previous) through the method parameters quickly. What's the shortcut to do this in android studio.

```
private void updatePersonalData(String frirstName, String lastName,int age,int weight,int grade,String nationality,....)
```

Comment: `ctrl+right`, `ctrl+left` can move the cursor between words

Comment: check all Android Studio Keymap, https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: ctrl+right, ctrl+left : only move through the next word. I really want to move fast through the parameters of method, so use the ctrl+right, ctrl+left is not effective as  I expect!

Comment: Having so many parameters for a function is not such a good practice. Use a `Class` instead.

Comment: "Having so many parameters for a function is not such a good practice" >> I accept. But sometimes I  maintain or fix bugs project, so this shortcut is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you imagine it would work but usually I use **CTRL + LEFT/RIGHT Arrows** to quickly navigate between words.

Comment: ctrl+right, ctrl+left : only move through the next word. I really want to move fast through the parameters of method, so use the ctrl+right, ctrl+left is not effective as  I expect!